# font padding works for some fonts but not others

Tags: fonts, padding

i'm really puzzled by this. I have three different fonts (p, question, answer) and whenever I use the p font, it works perfectly as I can adjust everything and it will work. However when I use the question or answer fonts, I can adjust almost everything (e.g. the background colour) and it works, but when I adjust the padding or margin, it does not work on these 2 fonts but it works for the p font!

I have the p, question, and answer fonts all in the same div - when I adjust the p margin/padding, it works, but it does not with the question or answer fonts.

I hope I've explained this well enough. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

CSS:

```
p{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 10px 0;}

question{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
background:#30F;}

answer{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
background:#F00;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your question and answer are not html elements (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list for an example of an elements list).

You need to have your question and answer as classes

```
p{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 10px 0;}

p.question{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
background:#30F;}

p.answer{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
background:#F00;}
```

And format accordingly...

```
<p>default</p>
<p class="question">question</p>
<p class="answer">answer</p>
```